# Terraform: How to add multiple option_settings to option, in option group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax, terraform

I'm trying to create an option group that requires an option with option settings that add multiple values.

See the following, scrubbed for sensitivity:

```
option {
    option_name = "VALID_OPTION_NAME"
    option_settings = [
      {
        name  = "foobar1"
        value = "foobar1"
      },
      {
        name  = "foobar2"
        value = "foobar2"
      },
      {
        name  = "foobar3"
        value = "foobar3"
      },
      {
        name  = "foobar4"
        value = "foobar4"
      },
      {
        name  = "foobar5"
        value = "foobar5"
      }
    ]
  }
```

`terraform validate` gives the following error:

```
[0m  on rds.tf line 112, in resource "aws_db_option_group" "rds-option-group":
 112:     [4moption_settings[0m = [
[0m
An argument named "option_settings" is not expected here. Did you mean to
define a block of type "option_settings"?
```

I've tried numerous variations of this syntax to no avail. AWS in the GUI has the option by default to include multiple option settings, so there should be a way to do it in Terraform as well.

The [Option Group docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_option_group) for Terraform unfortunately don't include an example where one option has multiple settings.

Among other things, I also checked out [this thread](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/issues/63) which didn't help me, I believe because I'm not using that module.

Any recommendations?

---

Answer, for any future viewers:

```
option {
    option_name = "xx"
    option_settings {
      name  = "xx"
      value = "xx"
    }
    option_settings {
      name  = "xx"
      value = "xx"
    }
    option_settings {
      name  = "xx"
      value = "xx"
    }
    option_settings {
      name  = "xx"
      value = "xx"
    }
  }
```

Comment: option settings is a block in the example, not a list. Use `option_settings {`. you can specify this same block multiple times.

Comment: You can also use the `dynamic` block with `for_each` so you don't have to type all the settings manually.